# Java Sort after GroupBy

Tags: java

How can I sort these into a SortedMap instead of just a Map?

```
    class Person {
        String name;
        double weight;

        public Person(String name, double weight) {
            this.name = name;
            this.weight = weight;
        }

        public double getWeight() {
            return this.weight;
        }
    }
    List<Person> people = Arrays.asList(
            new Person("Alex", 150.0),
            new Person("Courtney", 120.0),
            new Person("Billy", 180.0)
            );

    Map<Double, List<Person>> grouped = people.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getWeight));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the overloaded [`groupingBy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.stream.Collector-) that takes a supplier:

```
SortedMap<Double, List<Person>> grouped = people.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                Person::getWeight,
                TreeMap::new,
                Collectors.toList()));
```

Answer (score 3):

You could feed the result in a `SortedMap` like so:

```java
final Map<Double, List<Person>> grouped = new TreeMap<>(
    people.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getWeight)));
```

Comment: I used your code just to see if it worked. Sorry. I deleted my message then I saw you fixed it.